# Unexpected Error on Capability Validation when running Marketplace Test Kit of Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, marketplace, capability

I'm trying to submit an update of my application and the Capability Validation test of the Marketplace Test Kit is returning "[ERROR]: Unexpected Error". What a great error message.

Submitting the update to the marketplace also gives me the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: So, what has changed in your application for the update?  Have you added the required capability sections to the App Manifest file?  You haven't given us much to work with here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required capability sections are fine into to the App Manifest file. I tried everything.

In the end, I created a new empty project, copied all files to it and voilà: everything worked.

I will never understand why...

Comment: Unfortunately not. Since creating a new project and coping the files solved the problem I stop looking any further. Sorry.